# How to wire a light with multiple black/white/green wires from the ceiling?

Tags: light

There are multiple wires coming from my ceiling, 4 black, white, and green, and 1 yellow wire.

[image]

Our light has 1 black, 1 white, and 1 yellow/green.

I wired:
- the black on the light to the bundle of blacks from the ceiling.
- the white on the light to the bundle of whites from the ceiling.

Then plugged in a light bulb. The light bulb was ALWAYS ON no matter what light switch I toggled.

How should I be wiring this? Thanks.

Comment: Use the bundle of white’s for the white, connect the fixture black to the single white, and the yellow/green to the green bundle.

Comment: Correction the single white is actually yellow partially painted.  That’s switched hot, it goes to fixture black.

Comment: I don't think that box can be to code, it's over fill limits. You have nine conductors plus grounds plus a fixture = 12 counted conductors, which exceeds the allowed number for all ceiling boxes (unless they make them deeper than 2.25" which I have not seen)

Answer (score 1):

Yellow (and painted white) will be switched hot, connect that to fixture black.

The white bundle is neutral, the white from the fixture goes here.

Fixture yellow/green is ground and gets connected to the green bundle.